# translateZ not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transforms

I have been trying to hide a child element "list" behind the parent element "div2" using translateZ. It works fantastically in chrome but not on firefox. Some body please help.

Link to JSFiddle .   [translateZ on firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/4DjLP/97/)

```
.list {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  -moz-transform: translateZ(-1em);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1em);
}
```

Please find the image here [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VImb.jpg)

Image on the left side which is working correctly on chrome. Yellow bar is behind red div. Image on the right is from firefox in which yellow bar is in front of the red div - which was not expected.

Comment: hi can you show the image good and wrong?

Comment: Neither Firefox nor Chrome need the prefix and Chrome has not been "webkit" in years. Also, you are required to post your markup here, not a jsfiddle which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one: [mcve]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The `transform-style: preserve-3d;` isn't inherited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style), it has to be set to each descendent in the hierarchy to keep them in the same 3D space.

You have preserved 3D inheritance in `#div1` and `#div2`, but not in the 
`.sub` grandchild, so the lineage is broken for the `.list` grandgrandchild you wish to Z-move.

If you add it to your `.sub` CSS it will accept its child `.list` into the 3D space and apply the Z transform.

```
.sub {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @prkos. You saved my day.